# When we have page fault in demand paging , where do we get the faulty page from? From the Backing store or from the virtual memory?

Tags: operating-system

I'm confused between the difference of backing store and virtual memory. Currently studying memory management in OS

Comment: Term "virtual memory" in your question is out of place. What did you mean? As for your question, it depends on what kind of page that was. It might get free page, fill it with zeroes and put it in there. If content of that page is on backing store for whatever reason, its content will be read back.

Comment: @Ivan i was studying about page fault under the virtual memory. Now my doubt is, if there is page fault for a process, where will I get the new page from? From virtual memory or from the backing store?

Comment: Virtual memory is, you know, "virtual". It is just a set of addresses partially mapped to physical pages. So there is a fast physical memory and "backing store" which is a slower memory, but it can be used to offload some data to get more physical memory available.

Comment: In current form your question is unclear. You need to rephrase it, but it is better to be something specific, not broad "how virtual memory works".

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the term "backing store" refers to bitmapped displays. I've never seen it used with virtual memory.

In a virtual memory system, every page of the process address space region has a disk mapping somewhere. That is a prerequisite. That disk image of the process is the "virtual memory." That is where the page is loaded from.